# Can uwsgi handle request non HTTP?

Tags: python, web, wsgi

I love simplicity of [wsgi](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/what.html) code.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    return 'Hello, world'
```

It handles multiple requests with multiple processes, threads, on sub python interpreter.

But it seems handle only HTTP(S) requests.

How can I write non-HTTP Text-based protocol handler script on WSGI server?

Thanks in advance.

(I don't like to use [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), Concurrence)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WSGI is specifically designed to connect web servers to web applications; in other words it's completely oriented towards HTTP.

If you want to implement a different protocol, you should probably be looking at the lower level [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) interface.